# How can I get the author of an svn revision using the command line?

Tags: svn

I want to use the command line to send a repository location and a revision number, and get back some output that has the author of that revision in it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`svn info -r revnumber target` - the output will include a `Last Changed Author` line.

Comment: this one looks easier to parse

Answer (score 3):

```
$ svn log -v -r revision url://repo/path
```

Comment: this one also works

Answer (score 1):

```
svn info --show-item last-changed-author
```

Gives you the user name responsible for last change. No parsing required.